# Изменение текста js

Tags: javascript

Есть в `html`
такой код

```
<div id="otak"></div>
```

и js

```
newText = document.createTextNode("Загрузка.");
$('#otak').appendChild(newText) ;
newText = document.createTextNode("Загрузка..");
$('#otak').appendChild(newText) ;
newText = document.createTextNode("Загрузка...");
$('#otak').appendChild(newText) ;
```

Но почему то не работает, я  просто не знаком с JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то вы намешали и jQuery, и чистый JS... Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то возможно подойдет [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/wUnTE/)

Comment: Подключил <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
Ваш код все равно не робит

Comment: @NetSperes, код обернуть надо в следующую конструкцию:

    // или так
    $(function(){
        // тут jQuery-код
    });

    // или так
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // тут jQuery-код
    });

Answer (score 1):

Функция `$` jQuery возвращает не Element, а внутренний объект jQuery. Соответственно, у него нет метода `appendChild` (зато есть метод `append`, работающий аналогично). На будущее, пара советов:

1. Используйте инструменты разработчика, встроенные в браузер. Обычно они появляются по нажатию F12. В частности, консоль JavaScript покажет ошибки, возникающие при выполнении вашего кода
2. Если вы не знакомы с JavaScript, не пишите на нём. Почитайте для начала хотя бы пару статей для новичков или какой-нибудь учебник (например, [этот](http://learn.javascript.ru/)), это поможет вам понять, что происходит, когда вы выполняете тот или иной код, и не задавать подобных вопросов.
3. **НЕ НАЧИНАЙТЕ УЧИТЬ JavaScript С jQuery!** Сначала разберитесь с чистым JavaScript.

Comment: я в корне не согласен насчет jQuery,  эти операции с DOM вечно не совместимые между браузерами и перегруженной семантикой есть только засорение мозга, действительно чистый js попрактиковать стоит, но jQuery в этом нисколько не помеха.